# in C# Inheritace with 'where'

Tags: c#, generics

Anybody please explain the following code in details:

```
internal class InternalClientProxy<TInterface> : 
    ClientBase<TInterface> where TInterface : class
```

Comment: Does the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) not explain it?

Comment: please mention what specifically is not clear. Just the use of where? Without the clarity others will not be able to provide help

Answer (score 1):

It is a generic type constraint. In this case

```
where T : class
```

Denotes that T should be a reference type.

See here for details on the constraints: [Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

That means you can only have reference types in your `InternalClientProxy`

Some useful links for better understanding

[MSDN1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
[MSDN2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) explains the syntax.

> **Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)**
>
> When you define a generic class, you can apply restrictions to the kinds of types that client code can use for type arguments when it instantiates your class. If client code tries to instantiate your class by using a type that is not allowed by a constraint, the result is a compile-time error. These restrictions are called constraints. Constraints are specified by using the **where** contextual keyword. The following table lists the six types of constraints:
>
> ...
>
> `where T : class` The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.

Without the constraint the generic code might behave differently (among other things) depending on whether `TInterface` represented a value or reference type.